# ComboBox with Checkboxes inside, C++ Qt, select/unselect all checkboxes

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, combobox

I wrote a simple combobox with checkboxes as its items. When I select an item and press button, it shows what item I selected. But I would like to do something like this: I have an item called "all" - when I select it, all other items should be selected, and when I unselect it, all others items should be unselected. Any ideas?

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QComboBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

private slots:

    void buttonclicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->model = new QStandardItemModel(4, 1); // 4 rows, 1 col
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
    {
        QStandardItem* item;
        if(r == 0)
            item = new QStandardItem(QString("All"));
        else
            item = new QStandardItem(QString("Item %0").arg(r));

        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
        item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);

        model->setItem(r, 0, item);
    }

    ui->comboBox->setModel(model);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonclicked()));
}

void MainWindow::buttonclicked()
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0; i<ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
    {
        QModelIndex index = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
        QVariant v = index.data(Qt::CheckStateRole);
        int j = v.toInt();
        if(j == 2)
        {
            QModelIndex ii = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
            QString text = ii.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            qDebug() << text;
        }

    }
    qDebug()<<"";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**ui file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Check what was selected</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `qtslot` for this button such that when it is clicked/triggered you will iterate over all of the checkboxes within the desired combobox and edit their checked state.

Comment: for button, not for checkbox?

Comment: Correct. The action is when the 'all' button is clicked, what you do will be to the combobox's contents.

Comment: oh you don't mean a button, you mean having a literal item within the combobox named 'all'? I would make your life easier and a have button above the combobox that if toggeled would either select all or unselect all items in the box. Much easier and avoids having to teach the all item within the combobox how to manage the other items, which he generally shouldn't have to know about

Comment: yes, I meant item within combobox named "All" - when user select this one, all others should be selected too (same for unselecting)

Comment: @BrianBrown Another option would be to subclass the combobox and have the combobox class itself own and place the 'all' element there so that you can give it a custom implementation without teaching a 3rd party class about the internals of your model. (But do you select the all item when you are asking him to select all the other items? etc)

Comment: See my edit, I posted my gui - you can see how it looks. What I want to do its when user will select "all" combo, app should select all other combos. When user unselect "all" combo, all others should be unselected too. Any advices about it? Or maybe a piece of code of what you write? I dont write in Qt very often:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37972/discussion-between-upandadam-and-brian-brown)

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning how to use model subclassing while trying replicate the checkbox list using your code and have found a way to trigger a signal when checked status in any of the checkboxes populating the list changes.

Declaring a public slot in MainWindow.h:

```
public slots:
        void itemCheck(QModelIndex a, QModelIndex b);
```

Implementing the slot in MainWindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::void itemCheck(QModelIndex a, QModelIndex b)
{
    qDebug() << "check event";
}
```

And connecting this new slot to the *model's* dataChanged signal:

```
connect(ui->comboBox->model(), SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex, QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(itemCheck(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)));
```

<del>I think, it is possible to filter the event for the "All" checkbox and set the other ones appropriately.</del>
Managed to get it working:

```
void MainWindow::itemCheck(QModelIndex a, QModelIndex b)
{
    qint16 i;
    QModelIndex cycleIndex;
    // if "All" checked
    if (a.row() == 0)
    {
        // blocking new dataChanged singnal while managing other checkboxes
        ui->comboBox->model()->blockSignals(true);
        // setting other checkboxes appropriately
        if (a.data(Qt::CheckStateRole).toBool())
        {
            for (i = 1; i<ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
            {
                cycleIndex = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
                ui->comboBox->model()->setData(cycleIndex, Qt::Checked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
            }
        } else
        {
            for (i = 1; i<ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
            {
                cycleIndex = ui->comboBox->model()->index(i, 0);
                ui->comboBox->model()->setData(cycleIndex, Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
            }
        }
        ui->comboBox->model()->blockSignals(false);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone learning Qt from scratch.